# Melted dryer wire

Tags: dryer

[image]My dryer stopped heating. Assumed it was the heating element. Upon investing I noticed 2 melted wires leading into the heating element. Is this just a bad repair first time around when the heating element was replaced, (poor crimp) or should I look into replacing entire wire harnesse. I plan on replacing entire element and fuses.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The heating element is probably still fine.

How ever the crimp connectors are not.

Crimping is fast but not so good connection for high current wires. It does not utilizes the entire contact surface leading to overheating from bad contact.

Once you have replaced and crimped again, use soldering to fill the crimp wire. That will give much stronger electrical connection.

Comment: Had this happen to a kettle. Took out old wires, sanded the crimp to clean up the old burnt marks, crimped and soldered.

Answer (score 0):

Heating elements on dryers generally range between 20 and 50 ohms. You could measure to check. In any case Ruskes is correct, not the best connection. I'm with replacing the element regardless.